# WPFToolkit:DataGrid was not found

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I create a new WPF APP Project and add WPFToolkit.dll to References, but when I try to use the WPFToolkit:DataGrid like the code below, an error appeared "The type 'toolkit:DataGrid' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built."

```
<UserControl x:Class="Canlendar.Control.CanlendarGrid"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Height="300" Width="500">
 <Grid>
  <toolkit:DataGrid></toolkit:DataGrid>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

1. WPFToolkit.dll had been added to the project;
2. the WPFToolkit.dll was built in Debug folder;
3. the controls in WPFToolkit.dll can be added to the user control in C# code, but can't be used in XAML Designer;
4. Although there is an error, but the project was built successfully and even the app can run correctly, OMZ!!

I can't figure out what the problem is, anyone can help me?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of .NET and Visual Studio do you use? If you use the latest version of .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010, DataGrid control is already build in and it's also available in standard visual component toolbar (left side) when you create WPF Window or XBAP.

I suspect you're using previous version of DataGrid in the WPF Toolkit for Visual Studio 2008, and you must verify the installation of WPF Toolkit. Also don't forget to clean the solution and rebuild it again.

**UPDATE:** based on previous answerer, [the issue on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632407/wpf-designer-fails-when-self-referencing-project-assembly-in-xaml-in-64-bit-app-with-visual-studio-2010) is related to 64bit target development only, not in 32bit target. Do you code in 64bit? Just use 32bit and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answering.But I'm using.net3.5 and VS2008 not the 4.0 vs2010.In fact wpftoolkit works well in other projects except this project which is recently created.

Comment: Thanks again.It confussed me.There is another WPF APP which is also using the WPFToolkit and it works well,but when I created a new project,it failed....OMZ

Comment: @PekingOperaInAlaska do you use 64bit? if you use 64bit as target, the error will show up again. simply use 32bit, and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks.But I do not understand the meaning of "use 64bit as target".Does it mean that I should re-install my system with a 32bit win7 or XP?Could you please give me some details,thanks!

Comment: UPDATE:I have tried to build this project in x86,it doesn't work well....er...OMZ

Answer (score 0):

This might be a known issue for the XAML editor. You can find more information [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632407/wpf-designer-fails-when-self-referencing-project-assembly-in-xaml-in-64-bit-app-with-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: The issue is only valid for 64bit target environment, not in 32bit.

Comment: that's why I wrote "might be" :)

Comment: Thank you!My system is WIN7 64bit,the develop environment is .net 3.5/vs2008,but it may not be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are working with Visual  Studio 2015, kindly  include  the following WPFToolKit, WPFToolkit.VisualStudio. Design. The snapshot of my environment is attached  below

[image]